# Simplifying a Double Summation

Tags: calculus, number-theory, summation

Let $f_n(k)$ be defined as $$f_n(k)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i\left(\frac{j}{i}\right)^k$$ Can $f_n(k)$ be simplifying down to an expression without summations?

By simply [graphing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ke93bvedor) $f_n(k)$, it is clear there is a horizontal asymptote at $y=n$, but seemingly no vertical asymptote. If the question above does not have a solution, what bounds can be implied on this summation, both upper and lower?

Comment: Probably no, as $f_n(2) = \frac 2 3 n + \frac 1 6 n^2 + \frac 1 6 H_n$, where $H_n$ denotes the $n$th harmonic number.

Comment: As pointed out above a closed form expression for $f_n(k)$ doesn't seem to be in the cards. However one can employ the Bernoulli polynomials to give an alternative expression, since $\sum_{j=1}^i j^k=\frac{B_{k+1}(i+1)-B_k(0)}{k+1}$ where $B_k(x)$ is the $kth$ Bernoulli polynomial.